# how to output fitted time series data using facebook prophet?

Tags: python

I am using Facebook Prophet for time series forecasting.  After model fitting, I'd like to output the data of fitted time series data, for example, the center deep blue line.

```
model = Prophet(yearly_seasonality=4)
model.fit(df)
future = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=365)
forecast = model.predict(future)
fig = model.plot(forecast)
add_changepoints_to_plot(fig.gca(), model, forecast)
plt.show()
```

I tried to use below code, and I got 2 orange lines for 'yhat'. I am not sure why there are 2 lines? I also tried the other columns in forecast.columns and none of them match the deep blue line.

forecast.columns

Index(['ds', 'trend', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper', 'trend_lower', 'trend_upper',
'additive_terms', 'additive_terms_lower', 'additive_terms_upper',
'weekly', 'weekly_lower', 'weekly_upper', 'yearly', 'yearly_lower',
'yearly_upper', 'multiplicative_terms', 'multiplicative_terms_lower',
'multiplicative_terms_upper', 'yhat'],
dtype='object')

Thanks for your help.

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.scatter(df['ds'], df['y'])
plt.scatter(forecast['ds'], forecast['yhat'])
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Total daily sales (£)')
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]